# index is out of bounds

Tags: python, bounds

Here is my program, I don't understand why this error appears line 41 :"index 60 is out of bounds for axis 0 in size 60", it's the game of life and I tried to do it by myself because as I'm new in python it was hard to understand the ones on internet...

```
import numpy as np

rows=60
cols=60
size=rows*cols
nb_steps=300
array=np.random.randint(0,high=2, size=size,dtype=int).reshape(rows,cols)
next_state=np.zeros((rows,cols),dtype=int)
alive=1
dead=0
grid=np.int(size)

def nb_neighbors(grid):
 neighbors=np.zeros((rows,cols),dtype=int)
    for x in range (rows):
       for y in range (cols):
        if x==0 and y==0:
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x-1][y]+grid[x-1][y+1]+grid[x][y+1]
        if x==0 and y==59:
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x+1][y]+grid[x+1][y-1]+grid[x][y-1]
        if x==59 and y==0:
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x][y+1]+grid[x+1][y+1]+grid[x+1][y]
        if x==59 and y==59:
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x][y-1]+grid[x-1][y-1]+grid[x-1][y]      
        if y-1==0:
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x-1][y]+grid[x+1][y]+grid[x-1][y+1]+grid[x][y+1]+grid[x+1][y+1]
        if y+1==0:
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x-1][y-1]+grid[x][y-1]+grid[x+1][y-1]+grid[x-1][y]+grid[x+1][y]
        if x-1==0:
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x][y-1]+grid[x+1][y-1]+grid[x+1][y]+grid[x][y+1]+grid[x+1][y+1]
        if x+1==0:
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x-1][y-1]+grid[x][y-1]+grid[x-1][y]+grid[x-1][y+1]+grid[x][y+1]
        else :
            neighbors[x][y]=grid[x-1][y-1]+grid[x][y-1]+grid[x+1][y-1]+grid[x-1][y]+grid[x+1][y]+grid[x-1][y+1]+grid[x][y+1]+grid[x+1][y+1]
return neighbors

def next_state(old): 
  next_state=np.zeros((rows,cols),dtype=int)
  neighbors=nb_neighbors(old)
    for x in range (rows):
        for y in range(cols):

        if old[x][y] == alive and (neighbors[x][y] == 2 or neighbors[x][y] == 3):
            next_state[x][y] = alive

        if old[x][y] == dead and neighbors[x][y] == 3:
            next_state[x][y] = alive    
        else :
            next_state[x][y]= dead
return next

following=next_state(array)

  for i in range (nb_steps):
      following=next_state(following)

print (following)
```

Comment: `grid[x][y + 1]` when you’re at the bottom of the grid is…? `grid[x + 1]` when you’re on the right? (Swap “right” and “bottom” if `x` represents a row.)

Comment: Typical access into a 2D array is (row, column) or (y, x)

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan and cricket_007 for your answers !! I'm gonna try this and I'll let you know !

Comment: But I don't really understand why do I have to change x and y ?